# UITableView reloadSection causes cellForRowAtIndexPath to be called for ALL rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app with a `UITableViewController`, initially with a single section with a single row (that says "Loading..." in it). It fetches some data from the internet, at which point it makes the following call:

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexPath indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This is necessary because after fetching the data, there's now a lot of rows, rather than just the 1 there was initially (so asking the table view for the list of visible cells isn't a possibility, since it just returns the 1 old one)

The trouble is that it's then calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method for *every single row*, not just the visible ones. I've verified that by putting some logging into the method. If I switch the line to a simple `[tableView reloadData]` then it only calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the first few rows, until the point where you scroll and others come into view. This happens on my iOS4 iPod Touch and also in the iOS5 simulator.

I have about 300 rows and it's making it very slow to load and usually crashes on my iPod Touch.

The reason I'm not just using `reloadData` is that I want the addition of the new rows to be animated, whereas `reloadData` just makes them suddenly appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: I've editted my question with a clarification: `indexPathsForVisibleRows` isn't an option, since the underlying data has changed, and it only returns the one old cell that was there to start with (it doesn't include any of the new rows that should be added)

Comment: okey, you're right, not an option then ;) but i think, if you call [NSIndexPath indexSetWithIndex:0], the tableView has to load all cells/data, because how should the tableView know, if there isn't any data for section 0 at the end of your providing data.

Comment: But if that's the case, why is `reloadData` smart enough to get it right?

Comment: good question, and i can be wrong, but i take a guess. reloadData first calls numberOfCells so it knows that there is now more then one row. and then does the indexPathsForVisibleRows... just guessing ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using for adding rows to the table:

```
NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = previousTableDataCount; i < [tableData count]; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }

    // Apply the updates.
    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [tableView endUpdates];
```

It doesn't reload all data, it just insert the new rows at the bottom of the existing tableView.
The tableData array is the table's datasource array and the previousTableDataCount is the index with the items the tableData array had before inserting the new data from the internet...

Comment: I'm not sure this would help - given that the table starts off with a single row, this would still basically have to load *all* of the cells, right?